# How to cluster color images based on color value?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to cluster a sample color image of a surface into known number of clusters defined by user.
I know that intensity variations due to lighting artifacts is troubling.
Does anyone know a robust intensity-invariant algorithm to implement this clustering with known number of clusters?

### additions:

I'm using matlab.

Clues I have found till now are using `HSV` and `CIE Lab` color spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several color models that separate color from intensity information.
Pick one and use it.

Matlab supports several conversions:

RGB->YIO

RGB->HSV

RGB->YCbCr

...

https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/understanding-color-spaces-and-color-space-conversion.html

Comment: I know these spaces, but I don't know which one is better for color segmentation under intensity variation.

Comment: @MJay unless that intensity variation does not cause any of your RGB values to become saturated or 0 there should be no influence at all. as I said they SEPARATE intensity from colour information. just spend a few minutes and see how Hue is calculated and you'll know the answer. if your requirements are too strict you should use a spectrometer anyway...